# Array splitting and getting unique array ids

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have such array, where each key value contains meta information of picture divided by  comma.
For the meta information `A,B,C`, `A` represents the ID of the picture, `B` the order of picture and `C` the color.

```
Array ( [0] => 657,1,1
        [1] => 658,2,1
        [2] => 659,3,1
        [3] => 660,4,1
        [4] => 661,5,1
        [5] => 662,6,1
        [6] => 663,7,1
        [7] => 875,15,3
        [8] => 877,17,3
        [9] => 874,14,3
        [10] => 869,9,2
        [11] => 872,12,2
        [12] => 959,13,2 )
```

I want to get a list of unique colors from all of array value. In such example it would be

```
echo  element[0]; result = 1
echo  element[1]; result = 2
echo  element[2]; result = 3  <- edited
```

and so on, if there is more than 3 colors in array.

Can you please help me on that? These array things are really hard for me.

Comment: What language is this? Looks kind of like PHP, but there's no `$` before the variables.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Why is the third result `element[3]`, not `element[2]`?

Comment: Barmar, did it. Yes it is PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly ...

```
$colors = array();
$list = Array ( 0 => '657,1,1', 1 => '658,2,1', 2 => '659,3,1', 3 => '660,4,1', 4 => '661,5,1', 5 => '662,6,1', 6 => '663,7,1', 7 => '875,15,3', 8 => '877,17,3', 9 => '874,14,3', 10 => '869,9,2', 11 => '872,12,2', 12 => '959,13,2' );
foreach ($list as $k=>$v){
    list( $id, $order, $color ) = explode(',',$v);
    $colors[] = $color;
}
$colors = array_unique($colors);
sort($colors);
```

... will create an array `$colors` that has ...

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

... where 1,2,3 are the colors found in the `$list`

Comment: Noekio, I need more the unique from the colors, not the count of them.

Comment: Cool. Be sure to hit the 'answered' checkmark on this or any other of your questions whose answers worked for you. This helps others see what worked for you, and will improve the odds of your questions being answered in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you want:

```
$element = array_values(array_unique(array_map(function($x) {
  $meta = explode(',', $x);
  return $meta[2];
}, $input)));
sort($element);
```

Comment: this is great but he result has strange keys

`Array ( [0] => 1 [7] => 3 [10] => 2 )`

Comment: Added a call to `array_values()` to renumber them from 0.

Comment: This is great! Is it possible to order them by values, like that `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )` ?

Comment: Use `asort()`. Do you have a PHP book? There's a whole chapter on arrays that should explain everything you can do with them.

Comment: Thanks Baramr, i have a lot of them, but I have no time to read :)  I think better learing is by doing something. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Damn, Cannot figure about about that asort function, It does not work as expected, can you please help a little more?

Comment: Actually, in this case it's just `sort()` that you need. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
$array = array ( '657,1,1', '658,2,1', '659,3,1' );
function getColor($a) {
    $a = explode(',', $a);
    return $a[2];
}
echo getColor($array[0]);
```